# script manager not working in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager

I`m trying to show a message to user after the form submitted and want to return the id that i got from db inside the message like bellow

```
int reqid = come from database;

string scrp = "<script>alert('your request submitted with number " + reqid.ToString() + " successfully !');'</script>";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this , GetType(), "alert", scrp , true);
```

I don`t know why the script not working .

I`m using ajax features in my page .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<script>` Tags and Plz try the below code

```
int reqid = come from database;

string scrp = "alert('your request submitted with number " + reqid.ToString() + " successfully !');";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this , this.GetType(), "alert", scrp , true);
```

Comment: hahahaha , thanks a lot man , i almost got crazy because of this .